# How do I acess Node Attribute and Node values in XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML file and it goes as below and trying to bring out the Node Attribute value from Node Value

How to use XML Deserializer to access the nodes and its values

```
<Roots>
    <Root id="XYZ">
                
        <Select val = "SELECT0">
            <Pin val = "00"> A </Pin>
            <Pin val = "01"> B </Pin>
            <Pin val = "02"> C </Pin>
            <Pin val = "03"> D </Pin>

        </Select>

        <Select val = "SELECT1">
            <Pin val = "00"> E </Pin>
            <Pin val = "01"> F </Pin>
            <Pin val = "02"> G </Pin>
            <Pin val = "03"> H </Pin>

        </Select>
    </Root>
</Roots>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your Xml file content is not correct, eg

```
        <Select val = "SELECT0">
        <Pin> val = 00> value0 </Pin>
```

what is following?

> val = 00> value0

You can try serialize/deserialize your xml file to POCO classes by some framework, eg visit : https://github.com/ExtendedXmlSerializer/home

Following are some advises:

1. Create a **Roots** class which only contain a **Root** class as a property.
2. The **Root** class should has:

   - a property **id**, which should mapping to the xml attribute *id*.
   - a property of **Selector** class.
   - a collection property of **Select** class, eg. `List<Select>`;
3. The **Selector** class should has a collection property `List<Register>`, and class **Register** should has properties mapping to attribute **name** and **value**;
4. The **Select** class should has a property mapping to attribute **val**, and a collection property `List<Pin>`.
5. The **Pin** class should has a property mapping to attribute **val**, and another property mapping to value.

Here is some POCO codes:

```
    public class Roots
    {
        public Root root { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Selector selector { get; set; }
        public List<Select> selects { get; set; }
    }

    public class Selector
    {
        public List<Register> Registers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Register
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Select
    {
        public string val { get; set; }
        public List<Pin> Pins { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pin
    {
        public string val { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

Highly recommend using good naming, maybe this help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines

Comment: val = 00> value0
Consider there are 4 pins (Pin0, Pin1, Pin2 and Pin3) and the values are assigned to these pins.
For example:

value0 is the value of Pin0,

value1 is the value of Pin1,

value2 is the value of Pin2,

value3 is the value of Pin3

Comment: So as I mentioned, The Select class should has a collection property List<Pin> which contain 4 Pin objects.